# Use anchors in "Select" drop down list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, user-interface, drop-down-menu

Alright, so I have a currently functioning drop down list that displays a hidden div of content on the same page when that items is selected from the dropdown. The problem is I need to be able to have this same code as an anchor or something that will allow me to call up that particular section either when referencing that page from another page or by simply navigating back to the page after having moved forward in the content.

Here is the script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">`
jQuery(function($) {
$('.box').hide();
$('#option1').show();
$('#category_select').change(function () {
$('.box').hide();
$('#'+$(this).val()).show();
});
});
</script>
```

And my page content:

```
<div id="mental_lever_collection">
<div class="menu"><span class="title">Choose a Mental Lever Collection</span>
<select id="category_select" class="select">
<option value="#option1">Mental Levers &amp; Leveraged Thinking</option>
<option value="#option2">Zero Aggression Basics</option>
</select></div>
<div id="option1" class="box">

Some Content
</div>
<div id="option2" class="box">

Some Content
</div>
</div>
```

If you have any ideas on how to tweak this to get the desired effect it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what do you mean by an anchor?

Comment: @jmore009: I believe the question is about AJAX bookmarking. (Not necessarily AJAX, but those keywords should give plenty of hits. No time to write full answer though.)

Comment: To clarify - I'm looking for the dropdown "options" to produce the name of the anchor for example: the url of the page is example.com/mental-levers and after an option is selected I would like it to be appended to be example.com/mental-levers#option1. By doing this I hope to accomplish a method by which I can reference that page with a specific anchor and the content of that selection will display.

Answer (score 0):

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/0316dfL2/)

Try this

```
$(document).ready( function() {
$('.box').hide();
$('#option1').show();
$('#category_select').change(function () {
$('.box').hide();
    var test = $(this).val();
    console.log(test);
$(test).show();
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an extra '#' in your code.
Please change `$('#'+$(this).val()).show();` to `$($(this).val()).show();`

Hope this help you to solve the problem : 
Full  jquery code

```
<script type="text/javascript">`
jQuery(function($) {
$('.box').hide();
$('#option1').show();
$('#category_select').change(function () {
$('.box').hide();
$($(this).val()).show();
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but this doesn't change anything, I'm looking for the dropdown "options" to produce the name of the anchor for example: the url of the page is http://example.com/mental-levers and after an option is selected I would like it to be appended to be http://example.com/mental-levers#option1